# Google Drive API Client (Python): retrieve permissions

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I got this error about with Google Drive API example.Can you help me ?
I used an old Google project (that use Blogger API - work well) by add new Enable API for Google Drive into Google project.
I make a new python file and I try to deal with Google Drive API.
I used same json credentials.

My source code: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/xTH1zf3tEtLH5~zvuAHf8Q

```
def retrieve_permissions(service, file_id):
  """Retrieve a list of permissions.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to retrieve permissions for.
  Returns:
    List of permissions.
  """
  try:
    permissions = service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
    return permissions.get('items', [])
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
  return None
```

the main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    served = get_service()
    print "-------"
    print retrieve_permissions(served,'client_secret_driv.json')
    print "======="
```

The error is

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python27/goo_drive_002.py
-------
An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/client_secret_driv.json/permissions?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
None
=======

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Modification points :

1. In order to retrieve the permissions of file, the file ID is required. In your script, filename is given for `fileID` of `service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id).execute()`. So an error occurs. For this, it retrieves file ID from file name Using `service.files().list()`.
2. When you want the permission data from response, please change from `permissions.get('items', [])` to `permissions.get('permissions', [])`

#### Modified script :

```
file_name = 'client_secret_driv.json'
file_id = service.files().list(q="name='" + file_name + "' and trashed=false", fields="files(id)").execute()
permissions = service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id["files"][0]["id"]).execute()
result = permissions.get('permissions', [])
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: same error,  with this changes https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/-5P0GEGhjoRzmgp6iUC0Ig. maybe I need some special permissions into json file !? or a good tutorial , example for google drive.

Comment: @Cătălin George Feștilă In my environment, I confirmed that your modified script works fine. But, please confirm following condition. 1. Where is ``client_secret_driv.json``? ``permissions().list()`` is for retrieving the permission information of the file on **Google Drive**. if the file is not in Google Drive, ``file_id`` becomes empty. 2. About the error, is the same error on your question? If it's so, your modified script is not reflected my sample. Please confirm your modified script again.

Comment: 1.The client_secret_driv.json is the downloaded from creditentials Google Drive API - enable and is into the folder with my python script to make authentification (Is work with blogger API, see my test: http://python-catalin.blogspot.ro/2017/06/the-google-api-client-library-python.html)   2. this is only modified I make is https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/-5P0GEGhjoRzmgp6iUC0Ig to work with my script.

Comment: ``permissions().list()`` is used for retrieving the permission information of files on Google Drive. In this case, ``client_secret_driv.json`` has to be in Google Drive. ``The client_secret_driv.json is the downloaded from creditentials Google Drive API`` In your case, ``client_secret_driv.json`` is not on Google Drive. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Yes,I think Google Drive need special permissions , but the creditential json file is one for all API's project - this is strange ! maybe I need to remake this creditential file and this is the base of my question.